# ipad / iphone swipe

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I have this gallery that uses that ipad / iphone swipe from http://www.simplesli.de but on the iphone and ipad he swipe is a little hard to activate and it doesn't starting moving when I swipe like it has no feedback when my finger is moving across. Doesn't anybody know if there is any way to fix that with what I have implemented.

Here is the gallery I made http://leodruker.theorydesign.ca/about/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer on this however what I've used recently is: [jqtouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) which has worked great for detecting a swipe.  Another excellent library that I came across was [iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll).  This one has a bit more of a fluid feel to it.  Hopefully this is helpful to you!

Cheers